# zmodem not working without minicom

Tags: debian, shell-script

I want to upload and download file from and to the target board. I am able to send the file from the target board to PC using zmodem protocol to be specific using command

```
  sz -vv -b filename > /dev/ttyS0 < /dev/ttyS0
```

This will work fine only if the minicom is running in the PC. Since minicom is not installed in the target board am not able to send the file from PC to the board.

Can anyone tell me that , is there any way to send the file without minicom using zmodem protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You run the receiver side, `rz`, on the pc.